# appositive phrase

Tags: appositives

> His belly was swollen—sure **signs** that he would die soon.

It's an example sentence in a workbook. Is the use of *signs* correct? The plural looks weird.

Comment: It's fine, but there's no appositive phrase present. The noun phrase, "sure signs that he would die soon" is best analysed as a supplement, a non-integrated expression set off by intonation (and usually punctuation, as in your example).

Comment: I agree that the plural _signs_ looks wrong. So does the capital S in _Swollen_.

Comment: And note Colin's comment --- sure signs that you made a couple of slips!

Comment: That capital "S" was a typo. I will edit it.

Comment: @BillJ  Could you explain further,  how could the plural signs be fine,  if the speaker has only previously mentioned one sign？

Comment: @BillJ  Yes, you didn't say it was correct, but you said it was fine.  I'm sorry, but is there a difference？ I really don't understand.

Comment: @Robbyzhu My initial comment was intended to deal solely with the matter of an appositive phrase. By "fine" I meant the basic structure was correct. I should have pointed out the two errors in the sentence. Btw, you say the capital "S" was a typo. How are we to know whether the other errors were also typos?

Comment: Is 'wired' a typo?

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is incorrect. There is only one sign, so it should read:

> His belly was swollen—*a sure sign* that he would die soon.